# NodeJS app as windows service packed in .exe

Tags: node.js, windows, windows-services, node-windows

I'm creating NodeJS application which will be ran as windows service. Whole app should be packed as .exe so it can be ran on windows.
Let's take node-windows package that I'm using and create basic example (service.js)

```
var Service = require('node-windows').Service;

// Create a new service object
var svc = new Service({
  name:'Hello World',
  description: 'The nodejs.org example web server.',
  script: 'C:\\path\\to\\helloworld.js',
  nodeOptions: [
    '--harmony',
    '--max_old_space_size=4096'
  ]
  //, workingDirectory: '...'
  //, allowServiceLogon: true
});

// Listen for the "install" event, which indicates the
// process is available as a service.
svc.on('install',function(){
  svc.start();
});

svc.install();
```

This code is from documentation. As helloworld.js is script that will be runned, I will add just simple code example for it

```
console.log("Starting async function");

async function myAsyncFunction() {
  // Do some asynchronous work here, e.g.:
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
  console.log('Async work done!');
}

myAsyncFunction();
```

When I run this, windows service is restarted multiple times immediately without waiting for async code to finish (works fine when I run node service.js). What I can see in logs is  "Starting async function" but it doesn't wait for async code to finish. Is it even possible to run async code as windows service?

Comment: Hi Kevin, just saw your question. If you have not found an answer already, you can use https://github.com/vercel/pkg to package nodejs application into an executable. You can then use nssm to set it up as a Windows service. Please let me know if you have found some other method to implement it.